# Converting Javascript Object into PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I send this Javascript array into PHP page using form submit `{"1":"2","2":"2","3":"2","4":"2"}`

Now, I want to convert this array into PHP array, like this

`$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");`

So, this is what I tried:

```
$phparray = str_replace(':', ',', $_POST["questionandanswers"]); // Remove : and replace it with ,
$phparray = str_replace('}', '', $phparray); // Remove }
$phparray = str_replace('{', '', $phparray); // Remove {
echo '<br/>';
echo $phparray; // Output of this is: "1","2","2","2","3","2","4","2"



$questionandanswers = array($phparray); // Now convert it into PHP array
```

But it is not working. Looks like i cannot put `$phparray` variable here `array($phparray)`

But, If instead of putting `$phparray` variable in `array($phparray)`, If i put the output of `$phparray` manually, then, it works like: `array("1","2","2","2","3","2","4","2")`

What's the solution?

Comment: That's not a "Javascript array", that's [JSON](http://json.org).

Comment: `json_decode($json)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that your form submits a json object to the server so use json_decode with second parameter set to true to convert it to an array.

```
$php_array=  json_decode($_POST["questionandanswers"],true)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing here is, the object name is not always in a serial order: It can also be like `Array ( [3] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [11] => 0 ) `. So, how to access the object, without knowing it's name?

Comment: Just use foreach loop with if statment according to your condition.

Comment: Btw, you misspelled json_decode

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode` like `json_decode($json)`. It will return an object.
If you want array, use `json_decode($json, true)`.
See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php